# Update app via Google play, which is installed by APK file

Tags: android, installation, google-play

I have an app that is not deployed via Google play store.

It has it's own APK file server, and previously, it doesn't have "update" functionality. Because of it is special purpose app, so a user who need to update app, he need to just uninstall current app and install new app.

Now I need to update these already installed app via google play.

**Question is:**
Can I update app via Google play store, that is installed via APK file?

Tested environment:

- Google play service 11.7.46
- Play store 8.4.19
- Galaxy S7
- Released Koeran market only.

**I tried:**

1) Build three test APK Versions 1, 2, 3.

2) Deploy **Version 2** and update **Version 3** via Google play store.

3) **[FAILED]** Install APK **Version 1** via ADB, and cannot update via Google play store. (In google play page of my test app, I can see buttons "UNINSTALL / OPEN"

This is exactly what I want to do.

4) **[FAILED]** Install APK **Version 2** via ADB, and cannot update via Google play store. (In google play page of my test app, I can see buttons "UNINSTALL / OPEN"

Some of my colleague said this case is possible, but I couldn't achieved.

---

I found difference between signed APK and Google play extracted APK. By [binary compare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31417454/850347), many file was different.

[image: Compared Image]

Especially AndroidManifest.xml, this information was added in Google play-extracted apk.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.android.vending.derived.apk.id"
    android:value="1" />
```

It was possible to update old version apk that was downloaded from google play publish page.

---

I found below answer, but it seems not working in my case.

[Will apk installed manually (not from play store) receive notification when update becomes available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968634/will-apk-installed-manually-not-from-play-store-receive-notification-when-upda/17969116#17969116)

> you will receive updates / see the app in the Google Play "installed
>   apps" tab only if the two conditions will take place:
>
> the APK package name is the same as the one uploaded to Google Play
>
> the keystore used to sign the app in the play store is the same
>   keystore used to release the apk you install manually.

Comment: Why it's not working in your case?

Comment: @Bek Well, I guess so. In my "google play app", I cannot find my app in "installed apps list"

Comment: Is the `applicationId` in `gradle` the same?

Comment: is it the same apk on play store?

Comment: Yes, exactly same apk. Signed with same key, same `applicationId`. Only different thing is Version code, and installation method. @Bek, Have you ever seen this problem? and can you updated your apk-installed app via google play?

Comment: I made like this. I had previews versions of my apk that was installed from google play store, and pulled by adb. I installed it on emulator and checked update and there's is update.

Comment: Are you sure `applicationId` in `gradle` the same not `package` name in `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: Same `applicationId ` both in gragle, in `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: When you search your app on google play store is it saying `installed`?

Comment: @Bek I have updated my question. And, thank you for telling me your experience.

Comment: @StanleyKou - there is no way for google play store to understand source of install. App you have installed on clients mobile ( by sharing apk) will be allowed to be updated from google play store as long as keystore is same in both apks. They might not get an auto update if its off, they will need to manually update it..

Comment: @StanleyKou - you can try this in Beta mode.. Upload new APK ( give it 1 day to get reflected everywhere...) new version doesn't show up immediately on Google play Store

Comment: @AmodGokhale It seems that google play store know source of install. In my trial No.4, I can see "Uninstall" button, and if I click it, It shows "마켓을 통해 설치 된 앱이 아닙니다. 제거하시겠습니까?" which means, "This app was not installed from google play market. Do you want to uninstall it?"

Comment: interesting.. I just tried this test. Install an apk on device ( version 2) using adb then went to play store to look for latest version , we have on google play store version 3 and it shows me update option and was able to update it without any issue..

Comment: @AmodGokhale Oh, really? What was wrong in my environment.....? Thanks!

Comment: try clearing your play store cache ( If using multiple accounts.. try switching to different account ). Try it on simulator or different device... btw i have google play services version 11.5.09 ( not sure if that makes any difference )

Comment: Today I tested it. My current apps defaultConfig is `versionCode 24` and `versionName "1.2.0"`. I changed `versionCode` to 23 and `versionName` to 1.1.9 and installed to my device via adb and mydevice shows `update` on `google play store`. Just to be sure your keystore is the same as previews use `keyStore Explorer` to see .jks file content and  check if fingerprints are the same. You can download the program from this link http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html

Comment: @Bek, Thank you. But my environment, I was failed again. There will be some unknown condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to be updated by Play, the app has to be in the "User's library". This is a hard concept, but basically comes down to "has the user ever installed it from Play on any device". If the user has it in their user library, and the signature is the same as the signature on the Play store then the app will update.

If the user has never installed it from Play, then Play won't update it.

So what you want to happen won't happen, unless the user has previously installed it from Play on any device.

Comment: I think so. And my situation is just like this. But some users commented my question, it is possible to update adb-installed app. Now I think the settings are different for each Google Play country.

Comment: Is there any solution to the same problem in iOS?